# Cannot read property in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my script file

```
app.controller('userController', function PostController($scope, userFactory) {
$scope.users = [];
        $scope.user = { items : [] };
        $scope.editMode = false;

        $scope.addItem = function () {

                $scope.user.items.push({
                    Name: $scope.newItemName,
                    Value: $scope.newItemValue
                });
            };

         $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
                 $scope.user.items.splice(index, 1);
             };}
```

This is my html file.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ul class="nav">
       <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Items</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">

       <input type="text" value="ItemName" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="newItemName" required placeholder="name of new item...">
       <input type="text" value="ItemName" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="newItemValue" required placeholder="name of new item...">
           </div>
       <button ng-click="addItem()">Add Me</button>
       <li ng-repeat="item in user.items">
           <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>  <a ng-click="deleteItem($index)" class="delete-item">x</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I Click add me button i get an error as

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

I cant figure out the error and why it occurs. Please help me I'm new to angular js

Comment: Your $scope.user = null; should be comething else like $scope.user = {};

Comment: its because your "items" object doesn't exist OP. you're trying to loop through variable that is NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because your `user` property is null:

```
$scope.user = null;
```

Change it to an actual object which ideally has items property:

```
$scope.user = { items : [] };
```

Comment: hehe you beat me by few seconds :D +1 for you :)

Comment: @FeroozKhan are you sure you updated everything? Here is a [link to a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCINp4kkG01gp3pMK4jp?p=preview)

Comment: Is it just me, or I'm not getting any errors in the codepen link that you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Simple where is items if you have  `$scope.user = null;`

so simple do one thing add

```
$scope.user = {items:[]};
```

and then use `$scope.user.items.push(data)`

Comment: i have editing my script file the same error occurs.. @squiroid